# What does this error mean?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am trying to solve a system of two Euler equations with a constraint. I do not know the initial conditions and I thought to use `ParametricNDSolve` to solve the equations and find the parameters that solve the constraint. Here is my code:

```
rs[r_] = (3/(4 Pi u[r]^2))^(1/3);
A = (Log[2] - 1)/(2 Pi^2);
b = 20.4562557;
rin = 10^-10;
L = 2.87 u[r]^(10/3) r^2 + 1/18 u'[r]^2 r^2 + (-3/4 (3/Pi)^(1/3) u[r]^(2/3) + A Log[b/rs[r] + b/rs[r]^2 + 1]) r^2 u[r]^2 - 1/(8 Pi) r^2 \[Phi]'[r]^2 + (u[r]^2 + 79 DiracDelta[r]) \[Phi][
     r] r^2;
eqn1 = EulerEquations[L, u[r], r];
eqn2 = EulerEquations[L, \[Phi][r], r];
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, u[rin] == a, \[Phi][rin] == e, 
   u'[rin] == c, \[Phi]'[rin] == d}, {u, \[Phi]}, {r, rin, 1}, {a, e, 
   c, d}]
U[r_] := u[r] /. sol[[1]]
FindMinimum[Integrate[U[r]^2 r^2, {r, rin, 1}] == 79, {a, c,d,e}]
```

I get the errors:

> "Too many parameters in {a,e,c,d} to be filled from
>   {1/10000000000+Integrate`ImproperDump`newx}"
>
> The integrand r^2
>   \ParametricFunction[1,<<12>>[<<1>>],<<3>>,{NDSolve`base$22542,NDSolve`\
>   NDSolveParametricFunction[0,{ParametricNDSolve,Internal`Bag[<2>],None}\
>   ,<<6>>,{},All]}][r]^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all \
>   sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1/10000000000,1}}

What do they mean? How can I solve my system of equations?

Comment: We get a different error.

Comment: Which error? I am running Mathematica 10.0 if needed. @user21

Comment: do `u[r]`, `\[Phi][r]` have a definition attached to them?

Comment: @yosimitsukodanuri I have just re-run the code after a `ClearAll["Global`*"]`, but nothing has changed

Comment: what are the values of `a, c, d, e`?

Comment: @yosimitsukodanuri They are the parameters for `ParametricNDSolve`, I do not know their value I use `FindMinimum` to find it

Comment: Open a new empty notebook. Quit the kernel and copy the code form your post and you will get a different error.

Answer (score 1):

Define `rs` and `L` with `SetDelayed`. Similarly use delayed definitions for `eqn1` and `eqn2` eg `eqn1[r_] := Evaluate[EulerEquations[L[r], u[r], r]]`. After doing so and evaluating `ParametricNDSolve`, `sol` should contain the parametric solutions for `u` and `φ` which should look like this:

> [image]

Next, use `Set` to define `U` as in `U = u /. sol[[1]]`; now `U` is equal to the parametric solution obtained in the previous step.

The integrand function and the objective function need their own definitions:

```
integrand[U_, r_] := U[r]^2 r^2
objective[U_,a_, c_, d_, e_] := NIntegrate[integrand[U[a, c, d, e], r], {r, rin, 1}] - 79
```

Now, at this point if you experiment a bit with what you've got *eg.* with something like

```
RandomReal[{rin, 1}, {100, 4}] // (Apply[Quiet[Check[objective[U, ##], $Failed]] &, #, 1] &) /* (GatherBy[#, FailureQ] &)
```

what you get is a fair amount of `$Failed` and some more really big numbers. These two observations together seem to imply *to me* that there's some sort of a convergence problem with the integral, but don't take my word for it, I could be wrong.

Now, moving on along with the optimization part: after evaluating

```
FindMinimum[objective[U, a, c, d, e] == 0, {a, c, d, e}]
```

we get tons of error messages about `NIntegrate::inumr` followed by some `NIntegrate::ncvb` ones; the former are about non-numeric values while the later are about non-convergence.

If I'd had to guess I'd say that the parametric function is undefined for some values of the params a fact which produces the first type of errors while the convergence issue alluded to above is probably responsible for the later messages.

Hope this helps to get some attention on the Q. and have someone that knows better than me what's going on to give a solid response. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer to my question, after experimenting a bit and reading carefully the documentation for `ParametricNDSolve`, I have arrived to the conclusion that the definition of `U[r]`is wrong. The correct definition is:

```
U[a_, c_, d_, f_][r_] := u[a, c, d, f][r] /. {sol[[1]]};
```

After this I can integrate numerically:

```
4 Pi NIntegrate[U[10^4, 10^4, 10^4, 10^4][r]^2 r^2, {r, rin, rout}]
(*1.0306*10^-21*)
```

I still get the error:

> The integrand r^2 \
>   ParametricFunction[1,<<4>>,{NDSolve`base$195049,NDSolve`\
>   NDSolveParametricFunction[0,{ParametricNDSolve,Internal`Bag[<2>],None}\
>   ,<<6>>,{},All]}][a,c,d,f][r]^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values \
>   for all sampling points in the region with \ boundaries
>   {{1/100000000000000000000,27/200000000000}}

when using `FindMinimum` as before.